# Why was paper-based technology adopted on 23rd century starship?

Tags: star-trek, tv, star-trek-tos, star-trek-enterprise

In the 22nd century, there wasn't any paper-based technology on board *USS Enterprise NX-01*. Tablets were everywhere. Even for reporting, analyses were filed digitally. They even had a Microsoft Surface-type technology for group brainstorming.

However, in the 23rd century, on board *USS Enterprise NCC-1701*, they made tremendous use of paper-based technology. Even signals were printed on paper slowly like fax machines.

Why did Starfleet/the Federation degrade the level of technology in the future? Is there any canonical explanation?

Comment: Because when TOS was filmed, they couldn't imagine the tech we have now.

Comment: Are you saying this for a sci-fi tv series in which you could see teleportation & FTL speed (future tech for even today)..

Comment: Yes. Some areas of technology are easier to dream up than others.

Comment: In an era where the most modern computers were the size of one or two whole server racks today, and data storage units were as large as refrigerators, I'd say yes.  We have no real analog by which to compare FTL speed and teleportation technologies, so it's rather easy for us to fantasize about these to great extremes.  But, if you were to ask someone from *even the '80s* to imagine an entire computer *and telephone* in the palm of their hands, you'd probably just get a blank stare.

Comment: Because retro is cool.

Comment: I remember a scene with a message being printed slowly at a bridge station, but that was in The Cage, 13 years earlier, with Christopher Pike in command.  Did we see anything similar on Kirk's Enterprise?

Comment: Pure rumour/speculation:  I did once hear that the ST:ENT was going to address this, as well, if it managed a full 7 seasons.  It would've had something to do with the Earth-Romulan War, which was showing the first skirmishes even during the series.

Comment: @KeithThompson The ship was same & the century was 23rd century. Anyway, updated that spot for more clarification..

Comment: They did use tablets in ST:TOS, but there was also paper in use, but I don't recall it being widespread.  I think there was one signal on paper, kind of fax or ticker style (wasn't that in _The Cage_?).  Sachin, if you can cite several examples of paper, that might be helpful.

Comment: @TangoOversway The crew did show something or submit reports to captain on paper.. rather than on tablet (like ST:ENT).

Comment: I remember them using the early version of the PADD, which looked like a clipboard, in a way, and had 3 lights on it, but I don't remember much on paper.  Can you provide a few episode references?

Comment: Having read this question today, of course, I see [this image](http://chzsetphaserstolol.files.wordpress.com/2012/03/sci-fi-fantasy-i-wish-starfleet-would-break-down-and-get-me-an-ipad.jpg) not more than 1/2 an hour later...

Comment: @TangoOversway Even a single scene advocates for this question. Afterall, what was a signal-printing machine doing on a 23rd century starship?

Comment: I'm not saying it doesn't justify the question, I'm just asking for examples.  For example, in _Encounter at Farpoint_ Picard orders printouts for a specific reason.  It's possible the examples in TOS could be for specific reasons as well.

Comment: Federation IT department policies?

Comment: Perhaps it's process related? Flight control centers of Nimitz class aircraft carriers still use cardboard cutouts, push pins, and nuts & bolts to manage flight operations. I'm sure there may be a more technical way of doing that, but when you factor in training and process development, it still make sense to use 60-year-old technology. The same may be true for paper, even in the far future.

Comment: @Xantec: yup. 23rd century hipsters.

Comment: The paper you saw was actually an incredibly thin flexible tablet with a tactile surface.

Comment: Maybe improvement in replicator technology made paper no longer a material they had to worry about wasting?

Comment: @Zibbobz The problem isn't paper wasting. The problem is it's outdated. You can't search text on it. You can't modify anything on it. You can't sort any tabulated data on it. etc. etc.

Comment: @SachinShekhar - even given its limitations, there will always be the need at some point to have a static, tactile hard-copy that you can hold or pass around. We currently think of that as a piece of paper, but honestly it could be anything similar.

Answer (score 15):

Unfortunately, I doubt you'll find an in-universe explanation.  The only answer I can think of (and @Kevin has also expressed) is that it would have been very difficult for the writers of the mid-late '60s to have imagined the technology that we have today.  Even in the late '80s to early '90s, when STNG was in production, hand-held Personal Access Data Display devices similar to the tablets (Does anyone else think it's not a coincidence that one is called the i*Pad*?) we have today were science fiction fantasies.

I believe it is much easier for us to imagine things for which we have little or no comparable analogue in reality.  Faster-than-light travel and teleportation are two good examples you've given.  However, consider what the state of computing technology was in the mid-late sixties.  Computers were still far from commonplace, and not at all accessible to the common home.  Even the most modern machines were still as big as a minivan or larger, and mass storage units were the size of refrigerators.  The few cell phones that existed at the time had to be supported by suitcase-sized base stations.  So, imagine traveling back to that time and convincing someone there that some day you'd be able to carry a minivan, refrigerator, and a suitcase all in the palm of your hand!

The science fiction TV writers of the '60s could hardly have imagined that we would eventually have hand-held devices that have so much more capability, power, and storage - let alone that it would be achieved in just a matter of *decades*.  Even in the '80s, Orson Scott Card was far ahead of his time when he wrote about things like advanced hand-held gaming devices, hand-held computers, a world-wide computer network, and social media.

In making a prequel to a work of futuristic science fiction, especially when it's being made decades after the original, and *especially* after the technological revolution we've been in during that time, it's inevitable that some things in the prequel are going to be incongruous to existing canon.  Despite the obvious conflicts this would create, the purpose of this is still for believability.

In the 1960's it was very believable that the people of the future would still be working largely with paper documents.  Today, it would be absolutely ridiculous to propose such a thing.  The writers of Enterprise simply had to make some adjustments to suit a more modern audience.

Comment: On the other hand, in the first season episode "Court Martial", Kirk's attorney Samuel T. Cogley is seen as unusual for his love of printed books.  Kirk's comment is that "a computer takes up less room".  So the writers' level of imagination wasn't 100% consistent (not a criticism; that's to be expected).

Comment: @KeithThompson It's probable that Roddenberry conceived a computer of their time would have taken up less room than an entire library, as Cogley may have had.  However, it's also likely that he still did not expect technology to become such that a hand-held device would be capable of storing and displaying even a single book's data.  Perhaps the data density of magnetic media might have gotten that far, but the mechanisms needed to write, read, and display that data may have not.

Comment: @Iszi You've underestimated Gene so much. Haven't you seen on-board computers which were small? Plus, everyone was able to think that tech upgrades always take care of difficulties attached with it.. Portability was easy to think..

Answer (score 9):

In TOS, we see very limited use of printouts. McCoy's dietary instructions are handed over on disk. The Clipboards are tablet computers (and their display kept off-screen, mostly). We know that Scotty's tech journals are all ebooks - he reads them on-screen. Khan reads books on the screen by his bed.

Searching for the words paper, printout, and print out in the transcripts...

Paper:
Conscience of the King: this is the only episode where we see an actual paper document referenced as paper.
City on the Edge of Forever, Assignment Earth: they're in the 20th Century at that point in both episodes.
The Apple, The Deadly Years: retained idiomatic expressions. "chair-bound paper-pusher" and "fly in fly-paper" are seen.
A Piece of the Action:

Printout: only in an episode of TAS.

Comment: Looks like you haven't gone thru all comments on question.. In *The Cage*, many usage of paper can be seen (like submitting reports, signal print-out). Even one scene can raise this question..

Comment: @SachinShekhar: although that is just the first pilot. Did the rest of the series feature paper more?

Comment: @PaulD.Waite No. But, Kirk appeared 13 years later which is enough time to improve tech.. :) One episode can raise this question.

Comment: @SachinShekhar: ah, okay. If it is just *The Cage* that features paper, you might want to edit the question to reflect that.

Comment: @PaulD.Waite *The Cage* displayed it such that it looked like habitual thing.. :) That's why I am asking that way. But yes, *The Cage* can be mentioned. Let me thing for 'how'..

Comment: *The Cage* wasn't an episode, tho'. It was a failed pilot. The only portions of *The Cage* that really can be counted are those that made it into *The Menagerie*.

Answer (score 1):

One of the reasons fax machines and paper are still used today, is because there are a lot of things that aren't "legal" without a physical signature, comprising someone putting pen to paper. A decent in-universe explanation for all the paper in TOS that wasn't in ENT could be as simple as someone losing a very expensive lawsuit, for lacking a physical signature in the right place.

Comment: Means, they dropped this physical signature ju-ju in 22nd century & then adopted again in 23rd century?

Comment: Could have been a case someone lost at the end of the 22nd by not having a signed hard copy of something